# sql show the records and the total number of records in one result

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table like so

```
USERS

id name    location
1  anna     z
2  billy    x
3  Can      y
4  Diigy    w
```

i want to write a query that will give me the records and the total number of records
i know i can achieve them separately

```
Select * from users;
1  anna     z
2  billy    x
3  Can      y
4  Diigy    w

select COUNT(id) from users;
4
```

i am a bit confused on how would i combine this two together.

Comment: You can join the table with a subquery that gets the count.

Comment: Oracle or MySQL? Don't add inrelated tags.

Comment: how about you try answering the question  with somthing relevant
if you have nothing to add please move on

Comment: The answer may be different for MySQL and Oracle. You need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Ww3 Schools has a good source on this for you here:
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp

Create a table or a temp table with the Select you are using to get all the records.  Then JOIN the table with the count result and perhaps create a new table with combined table.

(to make the table based on the select statement)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_newtable
SELECT * FROM users;
```

If you made it this far all you need to do is JOIN this table with the COUNT, but the problem is what is the common factor between the count and all the other things in the table?  Or maybe you could do an INSERT statement followed by the count statement as another idea.

Comment: Why do you need to create another table?

Comment: Someone suggested JOIN as a method.  I was just offering a path to it.  There are many ways, but if OP can make a table with the select, now all he needs is to get the insert in there.  After he is done he can drop, truncate, or keep the results.

Comment: Just join with `users`, not need for `tbl_newtable`.

Comment: Add the results INTO the users table?  I mean I guess, but wouldn't you just want user data in that table?  And with a new fresh disposable new  table with only the exact data in play, that could have a count inserted into it without disrupting the user table, that is what I am thinking about with that.

Comment: He's not asking how to put the results into a table, he just wants a SELECT query that returns the combined results.

Comment: Yeah and then after the results are in this table, you just select the table and you are done.  You can truncate, drop, make it a stored procedure  that does all this and drops the table when done, what ever you want.  But yeah there is likely a more efficient way to do it directly, I'm just trying to teach one way that can work as well.

Comment: Actually I think you are right, you could cleverly craft a statement that mimics a table of just the data (the select) and JOIN that with the select of the count .. you are correct.  The link I provided to ww3 schools goes over all various types of JOINS and how to do them.

Comment: Linking to a tutorial is not really a useful answer. If he could understand this from tutorials he wouldn't be posting here.

Comment: I would offer more help but he hasn't presented the table to see what I am dealing with in order to insert the count.  How do you add a count to the users if the table is setup for user data and not built to support a count result?  That is my only hangup or I would do my best to type it for him.  But being it is SO, sometimes pointing them in the right direction, OP learns something on their own, so I was hoping to see some of that happen, but we shall see.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows function to combine your two queries

```
Select * from users;
1  anna     z
2  billy    x
3  Can      y
4  Diigy    w

select COUNT(id) from users;
4
```

---

Use `COUNT(id)Over()`

```
Select *,COUNT(id)Over() from users;
1  anna     z  4
2  billy    x  4
3  Can      y  4
4  Diigy    w  4
```

Comment: I like the brevity here, nice.